# Contextualizing in tag helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, tag-helpers

What does it mean to contextualize a tag helper?

```
((IViewContextAware) _html).Contextualize(ViewContext);
```

I am trying to understand what the above code does?

What happens if I use the code above? and what not if I dont.

[Reference](https://dzone.com/articles/using-aspnet-core-tag-helpers-for-image-layout)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Contextualize()` sets](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/926034ac4eed763cf7baf4acaeccba3272738d46/src/Mvc/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/HtmlHelper.cs#L181-L189) the `ViewContext` property of the `IHtmlHelper` where method is called on. Strictly speaking your not contextualizing the tag helper, just the HtmlHelper.

The `ViewContext` encapsulates all information about the current view being executed as well as the currently executing action (as `ViewContext` derives from `ActionContext`). Most of the HtmlHelper methods depends on ViewContext being set:  such as methods generating action links as it contains route data or for keeping state when rendering a form.

MVC will [automatically](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/321327f84b2b22dcff2e9beb06a9a64236c5cced/src/Mvc/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor/RazorPagePropertyActivator.cs#L88) call `Contextualize` on the the HTML helper (in fact, on all `IViewContextAware` implementations) for when executing a regular Razor view. The HtmlHelper is not a default concept for tag helpers however. When you inject it through the constructor of the tag helper, it will create a new instance which is not "contextualized" with any view information. Therefore you have to call it manually.

An exception will be thrown when a method which requires the `ViewContext` to be set is called.

**tl;dr**: always call `Contextualize` when injecting `IHtmlHelper` in your tag helper or it won't function properly.